# Class is not visible in managed package

Tags: managed-package, profile, unmanaged-package

I have created a VF page and extensions for VF page a extension. I am using custom object as  standardController and create a field set in the object which I am using in the VF page. On this VF page after entering the values in the fields they can upload file and hit save. This portion is done by the extensions. And add the page as the home page of the site after installing to a environment(Managed package). But hit save after entering the values and uploading the file it throws an error - Class is not visible. This same happens if it is accessed by the administrator. So I converted the package as unmanaged and installed it again in the same environment. Here this time it works. I have made the same setting for the managed and unmanged package but for managed it doesn't work. The fields, object and VF page are visible to the 'User License Guest'. But when I click on edit for 'Enabled Apex Class Access' the class is not found for managed package. Api version for both are class and VF page is - 29.0

My class and VF page code:

class:

```
public with sharing class ctrl_Candidate_Site{


public Candidates__c ca_Insert {get; set;} // For inserting Candidates records 
public blob Attach {get;set;}  // For attaching Resume to the specific record
public String fileName {get; set;}
public Attachment a {get; set;}
public Id jobID {get; set;}// To get the ID from URL
public Boolean isSaved{get; set;}// To know is saved successfully

public ctrl_Candidate_Site(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){    
    ca_Insert = new Candidates__c(); 
    ca_Insert = (Candidates__c)stdController.getRecord(); // getting records from VF page 
    jobID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('jobId'); // Getting the jobId from URL   
    a = new Attachment();  
}

public PageReference SaveResult(){

    ca_Insert.Name = ca_Insert.First_Name__c + ' ' +ca_Insert.Last_Name__c;
    if(jobID != null ){
        ca_Insert.Position__c = jobID;
    }

    Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
    Database.SaveResult sr = Database.insert(ca_Insert , false);

    //insert ca_Insert;

     if(sr.isSuccess() ){
        system.debug('Attachment value and inside is Success ' + Attach);
        if(Attach  != null){                    
              a.Body=Attach;  
              a.Name=filename;                 
              a.ParentID=sr.id; 
             // a.ParentId = ca_Insert.id;
              system.debug('Inside Is Success before attachmant get added ' + a );

              try {
                 if(a != null){ 
                    insert a; 
                    isSaved = true;
                }                 
             }      
             catch(System.DMLException e) { 
                Database.rollback(sp); 
                ca_Insert.clear();
                system.debug('If attachmant save have issues ' + e);
                ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Not able to attach your Resume. Resume format should be doc, docx, txt, pdf.');
                ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);             
             }    

        }
        else{
            Database.rollback(sp);
            ca_Insert.clear();
            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Please add your resume.');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg); 
        }            
    }
   else{
      for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
            System.debug('the error ' + err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            System.debug('Account fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());

            ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'No record get inserted. Please Try again.');
            ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
        }
    }


    if(isSaved == true){
        PageReference pr = page.Thank;
        //pr.setRedirect(true);
        system.debug('page url ' + pr);
        return pr; 
    }
    else{
        return page.Candidate_Site;
    }
  }



}
```

VF page:

```
 <apex:page id="Cnd_page1" showHeader="false" title="{!$Label.site.site_login}" standardController="Candidates__c" extensions="ctrl_Candidate_Site">

<apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>

 <style>
    h1{
        font-size:16px;
        padding-left:50px;
        font-family:'trebuchet ms', helvetica, sans-serif;
        color:#3366FF;
        line-height:20px;
    }
    .tableStyle{
        padding-left:50px;
        font-size:14px;
        font-family:'trebuchet ms', helvetica, sans-serif;
        color:#343434;
    }
    .cm_formCss{
         height:100%;
         margin:auto;
         width:960px;


    }
    .tdStyleFirst{
        height:25px;
        margin-bottom:13px;
        margin-left:2px;
        width:50%;
    }
    .tdStyleSecond{
        height:25px;

    }

  </style>
  <script>

    function onComplete() {

        var url = '/apex/Thank';
        window.open(url);
    }
  </script>


  <apex:composition template="{!$Site.Template}" >
  <apex:define name="body" > 
    <apex:form id="Cnd_form" >
        <h1>Candidate</h1>
          <table class="tableStyle">              
          <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Candidates__c.FieldSets.Candidate}" var="f"> 

                <tr>

                   <td class="tdStyleFirst">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!f.Label}"  />                          
                        <apex:outputText value="*" style="color:red;" rendered="{!OR(f.DBRequired, f.required)}" /></td> 
                   <td><apex:inputField value="{!Candidates__c[f]}" required="{!OR(f.DBRequired, f.required)}" />  </td>

                </tr>        

          </apex:repeat>
                  <tr>
                      <td>Attach Resumes</td>
                      <td><apex:inputFile value="{!Attach}" accept="doc, docx, txt, pdf" filesize="1000" filename="{!fileName}"></apex:inputFile> </td>
                  </tr> 
                  <tr>
                      <td></td>                          
                      <td> <apex:commandButton action="{!SaveResult}" value="Submit"/>
                           <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Reset"/> </td>
                  </tr>

          </table>
    </apex:form>
</apex:define>
```

I am not able to understand why this dose't work with managed but works with unmanaged. Even admin cannot access the class for managed package. 
Please guide me to get  the solution for this issue.

Comment: Is the VF page also part of the managed package? If not I'd assume that the controller inside the managed package needs to be global in order to be referenced from outside of your package. I'd say this is not a security restriction but a matter of the class access modifier in combination with the package IP protection.

Comment: yes the VF page and the class are the part of managed package.

Comment: if both elements are in the package this is indeed a strange behavior. try referencing the extension with the package namespace like extensions="myNamespace.ctrl_Candidate_Site"

Comment: Weird. It is worth enabling "developer mode" (a checkbox on User) as this turns on "extended messaging" where more detail is presented for errors reported back to the User - there is a chance that might give you extra information.

Comment: Is it possible that the error you are seeing is coming from page.Thank or page.Candidate_Site (i.e. that the save has worked and the problem is with the following page your route to)?

Comment: thanks page don't contain much just an Div with thanks message. And some css.

Comment: Are any controllers/classes associated with the composition page visible? If not, then that class will also throw an error.

Comment: Is the class global?

Comment: When you created the packaged, Did you check to make sure you had added the new class

Comment: This might be a silly question, But did you go past your debug statements at all? This would help us all know if it is an error on your class or with the class itself.